# Error in search and display records using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new in yii framework.I am doing seach recoeds in database and display in another page  using yii framework.My controller is Sitecontroller.php,view pages are search.php and search_result.php. and my model is job.php.My error is
"urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CUrlManager.php(440)".

My controller is Sitecontroler.php

```
<?php
class SiteController extends Controller
{
public function actionsearch()
  {
   $user_id = trim($_GET['id']);  
   $model = new Job ;
   if(isset($_POST['Job']))
      {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Job'];
        $title=$_POST['Job']['title'];
        $title=trim($title);
        $model=Job::model()->find(array('select'=>'*',"condition"=>"title like '%$title%'",));
        $number=count($model);
        if($number>0)
        {
          $this->redirect($this->createUrl('site/search_result',array('title'=>$title)));       
        }

      }
   $this->render('search',array('model' =>$model));
 }
public function actionsearch_result()
  {
    $title=$_GET['title'];  
    $model = new Job ;
    $model=Job::model()->find(array('select'=>'*',"condition"=>"title like '%$title%'",));
    $this->render('search_result',array('model' =>$model));
 }  
 }?>
```

My view files-search.php

```
 <div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'login-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>false,
'htmlOptions' => array(),
    'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true
),
 )); ?>
<?php
foreach(Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
    echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div>\n";
}
 ?>
    <div class="row">
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Keyword'); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'title'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'title'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

view file-search_result.php

```
<div style="float:right;margin-right:285px;">
 <h1>Search Jobs</h1>
<table width="200" border="1">
 <tr>
<td>SI No</td>
<td>Title</td>
<td>Key Skill</td>
<td>Experince</td>
 </tr>
 <?php
foreach($model as $models)  
 { 
 ?>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><?php echo $models->title; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $models->key_skills; ?></td
><td><?php echo $models->experience; ?></td
 ></tr>
<?php
}
 ?>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Any body help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems in this line

```
$this->redirect(array('site/Search_result',array('model' =>$model)));
```

You should try this instead

```
$this->redirect($this->createUrl('site/search_result',array('parameter'=>'value')));
```

Note:- **You cant send $model through URL as it is an object and that is why you are getting this error.**

**UPDATE**

In your search_result.php

change this code

```
foreach($model as $models)  
 { 
 ?>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><?php echo $models->title; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $models->key_skills; ?></td
><td><?php echo $models->experience; ?></td
 ></tr>
<?php
}
```

to this

```
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><?php echo $model->title; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $model->key_skills; ?></td
><td><?php echo $model->experience; ?></td
 ></tr>
```

**Explaination**

In this line

```
$model=Job::model()->find(array('select'=>'*',"condition"=>"title like '%$title%'",));
```

As you can see you have used **find()** for fetching the data. SO find() is going to return you  a single row (hence a single object) and not an array of objects. If you want to fetch multiple records then you should use **findAll()**

So when using findAll() your code becomes

```
$model=Job::model()->findAll(array('select'=>'*',"condition"=>"title like '%$title%'",));
```

and then you can use the same code as you were using in the search_result.php file like

```
foreach($model as $models)  
 { 
 ?>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><?php echo $models->title; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $models->key_skills; ?></td
><td><?php echo $models->experience; ?></td
 ></tr>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I had changed the controller code.please look it.Now shows the error Trying to get property of non-object

C:\wamp\www\yii\jobsite_orginal\protected\views\site\search_result.php(26)

Comment: can you tell which line is the 26th line?

Comment: <td><?php echo $models->title; ?></td> in search_result.php

Comment: <tr>
<td></td>
<td><?php echo $model->title; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $model->key_skills; ?></td
><td><?php echo $model->experience; ?></td
 ></tr>  In these way i got only one row,But i want all rows in that table

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be, that you have a bad naming of your actions.
You should use `camelCase`:

```
public function actionSearch()
...
public function actionSearch_result()
```

this is the naming needed by Yii, so it can find your actions.
The `redirect` method expects an action and without this I suppose it cannot find it.

Also the redirect expect a `controler/action` route, that means in your case it should read:

```
$this->redirect(array('site/search_result','model' =>$model));
```

Please keep in mind that the function is actionSearch_result with a Capital **S** but the route itself, is `site/search_result` with a lowercase **s**

Comment: Please look my controller code,i had change it.again shows these same error

Comment: you have it still wrong, please see my update - you should have renamed only the function names.. and additionaly also the `model->$model` should not be in a separate array. Please check the documentaiotn http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail

Comment: it does not matter if there is an underscore in the action name or there is an lowercase 's'.